# JSON over sockets - Is it a good idea?

Tags: java, android, iphone, json, sockets

I want to develop an Android app that exchanges data with a server. So far, I'm not sure about the software design:

I do not want to implement the server process as a web service, because the server should be able to push data to the connected (Android) clients.

Later on, I want to be ready for other clients like iPhone or Windows Phone. Therefore I think it is a good idea to choose the JSON format for data exchange between server and clients.

Is it a good idea to send the JSON objects over raw sockets? Is there any library that meets my requirements, especially the pushing of objects from server to clients?

Comment: Try [`Protocol Buffers`][1]


  [1]: https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be asking two separate questions here.

The first question is one of how to perform push of data to client devices. Push notifications on Android is a whole topic in itself which is discussed in a large number of SO questions. You could look at [Google Could Messaging](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html) or MQTT for instance.

The second question concerns the kind of presentation format for your application data, which is a whole separate concern to how you're going to perform push notifications. Yes, JSON is a fine format for exchanging data via raw sockets, as long as it suits your application, but remember that you still need some kind of message framing protocol over raw sockets that encapsulates the JSON data. In general though I would strongly advise against trying to do things over raw TCP sockets if you possibly can, and instead use an existing protocol library that sits above TCP, because writing your own message protocol can be more work than first realised.

For example, you might choose MQTT to perform your push notifications. You'd grab an existing MQTT library, and you could push out messages in JSON format without needing to be concerned about low-level TCP socket operations.

Answer (score 0):

you might have a look at [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/)